# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer este arreglo en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Buenas tardes compañeros, la verdad no soy muy bueno en PHP y me cuesta trabajo recorrer este arreglo:

```
[ 
  0 => [ genero => Acción y Aventura ], 
  1 => [ genero => Bélico ], 
  2 => [ genero => Ciencia Ficción ], 
  3 => [ genero => Comedia ], 
  4 => [ genero => Comedia ], 
  5 => [ genero => Documental ], 
  6 => [ genero => Drama ], 
  7 => [ genero => Historico ], 
  8 => [ genero => Infantil ], 
  9 => [ genero => Musical ], 
  10 => [ genero => Porno/Erótico ], 
  11 => [ genero => Suspenso ], 
  12 => [ genero => Terror/Horror ], 
  13 => [ genero => Western ] 
]
```

Lo que quiero es generar un arreglo del tipo: `array('Acción y Aventura', 'Bélico', etc)`

Podrían ayudarme?

EDIT

He agregado el siguiente fragmento de código siguiendo lo que ustedes me proponian, pero me di cuenta que ese arreglo es una serie de objetos 'Genero':

```
$a = array();

foreach($options['generos'] as $index){
    $g = new Genero();
    $g = $index; 
    $gen = $g->getGenero();
    array_push($a, $gen);
}

var_dump($a);
```

Cuando llamo a `var_dump()` esta es su salida:

```
array(15) { [0]=> string(7) "Comedia" [1]=> string(14) "Porno/Erótico" [2]=> string(18) "Acción y Aventura" [3]=> string(7) "Bélico" [4]=> string(16) "Ciencia Ficción" [5]=> string(7) "Comedia" [6]=> string(10) "Documental" [7]=> string(5) "Drama" [8]=> string(9) "Historico" [9]=> string(8) "Infantil" [10]=> string(7) "Musical" [11]=> string(8) "Suspenso" [12]=> string(13) "Terror/Horror" [13]=> string(7) "Western" [14]=> string(9) "Mi Genero" }
```

Que supongo que es lo que quiero lograr, pero cuando se lo asigno al siguiente fragmento de código:

->add('genero', ChoiceType::class, array('label'=> 'Genero: ', 'choices' => $a, 'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))

Sólo me aparece el índice o una serie numérica del 0 al 14, según yo debería funcionar de manera correcta, ustedes que piensan?

EDIT

Finalmente logré arreglar mi problema, sólo le agregue la siguiente linea:

```
$a = array_combine($a, $a);
```

Answer (score 3):

La idea es recorrer el arreglo (array) con un foreach y almacenarlo en otro 'nuevo', buscando la llave "genero" dentro de cada uno de los valores del arreglo inicial:

```
<?php

    $nuevoArreglo = [];

    foreach ($arreglo as $opcion) {

        $nuevoArreglo[] = $opcion['genero'];

    }

    print_r($nuevoArreglo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un *array* (o arreglo) que a su vez contiene arrays asociativos (tienen claves alfanuméricas como índices). Para convertirlo a un array normal, lo que tendrías que hacer es atraversarlo poniendo sus valores en un nuevo array.

Algo como esto (le he puesto las comillas para que sea ejecutable desde PHP):

```
<?php

$origen = [ 
  0 => [ "genero" => "Acción y Aventura" ], 
  1 => [ "genero" => "Bélico" ], 
  2 => [ "genero" => "Ciencia Ficción" ], 
  3 => [ "genero" => "Comedia" ], 
  4 => [ "genero" => "Comedia" ], 
  5 => [ "genero" => "Documental" ], 
  6 => [ "genero" => "Drama" ], 
  7 => [ "genero" => "Historico" ], 
  8 => [ "genero" => "Infantil" ], 
  9 => [ "genero" => "Musical" ], 
  10 => [ "genero" => "Porno/Erótico" ], 
  11 => [ "genero" => "Suspenso" ], 
  12 => [ "genero" => "Terror/Horror" ], 
  13 => [ "genero" => "Western" ] 
];

$destino = array();

foreach($origen as $index => $elem) {
    $destino[] = $elem["genero"];
}

print_r($destino);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación con Symfony, lo que en realidad no se es porque sólo me manda   el index. Es decir del 1 al 13

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma más compacta de hacerlo es con **[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php)**, que permite aplicar una función, devolviendo el valor de la clave `genero` de cada uno de los elementos del array.

**Código**

```
//Inicializar con los datos de la pregunta
$datosConGenero = [ 
  0 => [ "genero" => "Acción y Aventura" ], 
  1 => [ "genero" => "Bélico" ], 
  2 => [ "genero" => "Ciencia Ficción" ], 
  3 => [ "genero" => "Comedia" ], 
  4 => [ "genero" => "Comedia" ], 
  5 => [ "genero" => "Documental" ], 
  6 => [ "genero" => "Drama" ], 
  7 => [ "genero" => "Historico" ], 
  8 => [ "genero" => "Infantil" ], 
  9 => [ "genero" => "Musical" ], 
  10 => [ "genero" => "Porno/Erótico" ], 
  11 => [ "genero" => "Suspenso" ], 
  12 => [ "genero" => "Terror/Horror" ], 
  13 => [ "genero" => "Western" ] 
];

//Nos quedamos sólo con los valores
$datos = array_map(function($elem){ return $elem['genero']; }, $datosConGenero);

//Imprimir el resultado
print_r($datos);
```

Para cada elemento del array, la función devuelve el valor de `$elem['genero']` y lo agrega en `$datos`.

**Resultado**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Acción y Aventura
    [1] => Bélico
    [2] => Ciencia Ficción
    [3] => Comedia
    [4] => Comedia
    [5] => Documental
    [6] => Drama
    [7] => Historico
    [8] => Infantil
    [9] => Musical
    [10] => Porno/Erótico
    [11] => Suspenso
    [12] => Terror/Horror
    [13] => Western
)
```

<kbd>[Demo en ideone.com](http://ideone.com/m3rPDW)</kbd>

---

Las claves que aparecen (del 0 al 13) es la forma en que PHP muestra la estructura de un array. El resultado es lo mismo que si se hubiera gerenerado con
`$datos = Array( 'Acción y Aventura', 'Bélico'` ... `);`.